# TypeOrm findOrFail returning array of numbers as array of strings

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I have this entity in typeOrm with postgres:

```
@Entity('teams')
export class Team {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ name: 'users', array: true, type: 'varchar' })
  users: string[];

  @Column({ name: 'geo_places', array: true, type: 'numeric' })
  geoPlaces: number[];

  @Column({ name: 'distributors', array: true, type: 'numeric' })
  distributors: number[];

  @Column({ name: 'deleted', default: false })
  deleted: boolean;

  @OneToMany(() => TeamFieldAgent, teamFieldAgent => teamFieldAgent.team, {
    cascade: true,
    eager: true,
  })
  fieldAgents: TeamFieldAgent[];
}
```

When I findOrFail this entity, the geoPlaces and distributors are returned as an array of strings, I tried changing the @Column definition to something like

```
@Column({ name: 'distributors', array: true, type: 'int' })
```

or even

```
@Column('int', { name: 'distributors', array: true })
```

but I always get the same result.

And this is a screenshot from the postgres table [image]

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Seems like your syntax is correct (https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/test/functional/database-schema/column-types/postgres/entity/Post.ts).. you might have better luck creating a github issue for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution by adding a `transformer`, if there's a better approach please let me know

```
  @Column({
    name: 'geo_places',
    array: true,
    type: 'int',
    transformer: {
      from: (value) => _isArray(value) ? value.map(_toNumber) : value,
      to: (value) => value
    }
  })
```

The `From` property is applying a transformation when reading from the DB and the `TO` property is transforming when writing